# Update entity if already exists

Tags: php, symfony

**[SETTINGS]**

- Symfony 3.4
- POST data from another environment

**[PROBLEM]**

I'm currently persisting/creating a new entity directly from external POST data.
Once parsed, I flush all data to create my new entry.

What should I do within my controller to instead update my entity if it already exists in DB.

<kbd>**DeliveryBox entity**</kbd>

```
class DeliveryBox {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uuid", type="string", length=40, unique=true)
     */
    private $uuid;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $url;
}
```

<kbd>**POST data**</kbd>

`uuid=9a16dc07-902c-6115-6e9b-acb800968e25&url=https://sim9885.agni.lindenlab.com:12043/cap/4d6fe9c7-5fb7-77e8-8dbc-565dac4b0e49`

<kbd>**Controller action**</kbd>

```
/**
 * Creates a new deliveryBox entity.
 *
 * @Route("/registerbox/", name="register_box")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function newAction(Request $request) {
    $deliveryBox=new Deliverybox();

    //Parse POST data and set DeliveryBox values
    $content=array();
    parse_str($request->getContent(), $content);
    $deliveryBox->setUuid($content['uuid']);
    $deliveryBox->setUrl($content['url']);

    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($deliveryBox);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('deliverybox_show', array('id'=>$deliveryBox->getId(),));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `uuid` is unique, it may look like this.

<kbd>**Controller action**</kbd>

```
/**
 * Creates a new deliveryBox entity.
 *
 * @Route("/registerbox/", name="register_box")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function newAction(Request $request) {
    // Parse POST data
    $content = array();
    parse_str($request->getContent(), $content);

    // Get entity manager instance
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // Find existing delivery box by UUID
    $deliveryBox = $em->getRepository(DeliveryBox::class)->findOneByUuid($content['uuid']);
    if (null === $deliveryBox) {
        // If delivery box with current UUID is not found, create one
        $deliveryBox = new DeliveryBox();
        $deliveryBox->setUuid($content['uuid']);
    }

    // Update URL
    $deliveryBox->setUrl($content['url']);

    $em->persist($deliveryBox);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('deliverybox_show', array('id'=>$deliveryBox->getId(),));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Fun fact, I notived only now from your answer that editAction never had `$entity=new Entity`. Small correction for you, it's 'findOneBy(array('uuid'=>$content['uuid']));`

Comment: `findOneByUuid` is a magic method, which returns the same result as `'findOneBy(array('uuid'=>$content['uuid']));` does.

Comment: Ah~ Didn't knew. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
  *  This is sample code, which receives id of entity
  *  to edit and create the edit form and do the update,
  *  if form is submitted and valid. See this for more info 
  *  https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller.html

  *  Edit an existing entity.
  *  
  * @Route("/registerbox-edit/{id}", name="register_box_edit")
  * @Method({"POST"})
  *
  * @param Request $request
  * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
  */
   public function editAction(Request $request,  Deliverybox $deliverybox)
   {
     $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\DeliveryboxType', $deliverybox);
     $editForm->handleRequest($request);

     if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

         return $this->redirectToRoute('deliverybox_show', array('id'=>$deliveryBox->getId(),));
      }        

   }
```

All the best

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not using any forms here. they're not needed.